# Upload a file's content in Python

Tags: python, upload, http-post, standard-library

I'd like to use Python 2.7, without any modules not in the standard library, to upload a file to a web server (which will accept such requests). 
I know that this can be done by uploading the data as part of multi-part form data but, I am wondering if I can just `POST` with `Content-Type: application/pdf` (for example) and `Content-Length` set to the length of the file and, have the content of the post just be the content of the (in this case PDF) file. 
If so, what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: *I am wondering if I can just POST with Content-Type: application/pdf* It is up to the *web server* to accept that or not. If the server only accepts `multipart/form-data` for file uploads you cannot force the server to accept something else.

Comment: First determine if the server accepts direct posts without a multipart payload. You can do so using Postman (a Chrome extension) or the Python `requests` library, or even with `urllib2` from the standard library. Then restrict yourself to just the stdlib if you really must.

Comment: Direct uploads are otherwise perfectly possible. Just set the [`urllib2.Request()` data parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) to your file contents (open as binary), and set the `Content-Type` header. Done.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters the data parameter to urllib2.Request only accepts data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` according to the documentation (at least in Python 2.7). The server will accept such requests.

Comment: No, the `Request` object doesn't actually care. The documentation just tells you that the data will not be encoded for you, you need to provide readily encoded data *if you are using form post*.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters You appear to be right. This does work. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request), at least to my reading, seems to say that it data has to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It says "_data_ should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format." which I took to mean it has to be in that format for it to work as intended. This seems to be an undocumented feature to me.

Comment: `urllib2` grew organically and is not a great API. There is no officially documented way to do anything other than GET and POST requests either, for example, you have to subclass the `Request` class to override the `get_method` method. That's why the `requests` library is so popular, it does HTTP access *right*.

Comment: That's a shame. You'd think there would be a good solution for this in the Python standard library. Perhaps there is in Python 3 but, for this particular project, that isn't really relevant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, what? There *is* a solution, just set `data` to your payload. The documentation may be a little unclear here, but it is not telling you cannot use it for any other payloads. I've already posted that as an answer.

Comment: And the better solution in both Python 2 and Python 3 is to use the `requests` external library. I'm not sure why there is a hang-up over external libraries here.

Comment: You are right, this is a solution and, you are right, there is nothing wrong with it apart from the documentation. It's a shame the requests library isn't included in the standard library. In this case, installing external libraries isn't as easy as it is normally so, it is a less than optimal solution but, yes, normally, that'd work.

Comment: See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2424 for a discussion on `requests` and the stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

If the server will accept direct payload posts (as opposed to the file being part of a `multipart/form-data` POST request), you can just set the `Request()` data parameter to be the file data:

```
import urllib2

with open(filename, 'rb') as uploadfile:
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data=uploadfile.read(),
                              {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'})

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

The `urllib2.Request` object makes no assumptions about the contents of `data`, other than that the `Content-Type` header will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if `data` is set, unless you provide your own.

The `Content-Length` header will be set for you when you do this.